# How to add data in hibernate with many one-to-many relationships

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a Song class which has one-to-many relationship with other 3 classes - Album,Genre,Login. 
These are my POJO classes:

```
   @Entity  
   @Table(name = "songs")  
   public class Song implements Serializable {  
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name = "song_id")  
    private int songId;  

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinTable(name = "albums_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "song_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "album_id", referencedColumnName = "album_id"))  
    private Album album;  

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)  
    private String title;  

    @Column(name = "rating")  
    private int rating;  

    @Column(name = "artists")  
    private String artist;  

    @Column(name = "composer")  
    private String composer;  

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinTable(name = "genre_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "song_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =  
    "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "genre_id"))  
    private Genre genre;  
}  

@Entity  
@Table(name = "albums")  
public class Album {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name = "album_id")  
    private int albumId;  

    @Column(name = "album_name", length = 250)  
    private String albumName;  

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   
    @JoinTable(name = "albums_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "album_id", referencedColumnName = "album_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name 
    = "song_id", referencedColumnName = "song_id"))  
    private List<Song> songs;  
}  


@Entity  
@Table(name = "genre")  
public class Genre {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name = "genre_id")  
    private int genreId;  

    @Column(name = "genre_name", length = 250)  
    private String genreName;  

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   
    @JoinTable(name = "genre_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "genre_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
    "song_id",referencedColumnName = "song_id"))  
    private List<Song> songs;  
}  

@Entity  
@Table(name = "login", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = 
{"user_name"})})  
public class Login {  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue  
    @Column(name = "user_id")  
    private int userId;  

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable=false )  
    private String userName;  

    @Column(name = "password", nullable=false )  
    private String password;  

    @ManyToMany  
    @JoinTable(name = "user_songs_mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = " user_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "song_id"))  
    private List<Song> songs;  
}
```

I have tried this method in my service . But it is not working. There aren't any errors either. Please help me.

```
public void addSong(Song song, int userId) throws Exception {  

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  

        try {  

            session.beginTransaction();  
            List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();  
            songs.add(song);  
            Genre genre = song.getGenre();  
            Album album = song.getAlbum();  
            genre.setSongs(songs);  
            album.setSongs(songs);  
            Login login = new Login();  
            login.setUserId(userId);  
            login.setSongs(songs);  
            session.saveOrUpdate(genre);  
            session.saveOrUpdate(album);  
            session.saveOrUpdate(login);  

            session.getTransaction().commit();  
        } catch (HibernateException e) {  
            if (session.getTransaction() != null) {  
                session.getTransaction().rollback();  
            }  
        } finally {  
            session.close();  
        }  


    }
```

Comment: How can you be sure that there aren't any errors? You are ignoring the exception in the catch block. So if HibernateException occurs you just perform rollback and don't know if there was an error. I suggest adding logging in your catch block or otherwise modifying exception handling to determine whether some error actually happens first.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting a MysqlConstraintViolation Exception even when I am using saveOrUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Login` entity has `userName` and `password` attributes which aren't nullable, yet you don't set them when you create and save the `Login` instance, which is probably the cause of the `MysqlConstraintViolationException` you mention in your comment.

To fix it just set the username and password before persisting your entity.

Hope this helps. If it doesn't please post the whole stack trace of the exception so we can better determine what exactly fails in your code.

Comment: I have a unique key constraint on both genre_name and album_name in DB. org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [model.Album] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Crook' for key 'album_name' at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)